# 2x2 Gb DDR3 и Windows XP

Tags: windows, память, windows-xp

Объясните, пожалуйста, чревато ли какими-то отрицательными последствиями использование 2x2 Gb DDR3 в Windows XP или все же лучше (/правильнее?) использовать 2+1 Gb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это чревато тем, что вы можете увидеть несколько меньше (в зависимости от Мат.Платы и системы), чем ожидаемые 4Гб. Были ситуации, когда XP видела и 3Гб из 4х и 3.5Гб из 4х.

Если хотите быть точно уверены, что увидите свои 4Гб, берите 64х разрядную XP.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать 2x2 Gb DDR3 без проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Главное чтобы на планках герцовка была одинакова.

Comment: Полностью согласен с Dex

Answer (score 0):

а разве так уж и важна герцовка? имхо, та планка, у которой частота выше, будет работать по пониженной частоте другой планки.а вот чтобы увидеть все 4 Гига да, придётся х64 ставить. Правда, как мне говорили, увеличения в производительности по сравнению с 3-мя Гигами можно и не увидеть.

Comment: Каждый МГц стоит дороже, поэтому платить больше, чтобы получать меньше - не есть хорошо. Более того, гуру советовали в свое время даже брать одинаковых производителей из той же серии. Малые различия в синхронизации (CL) и т.п. могли вообще отключать одну из планок. Сейчас, думаю, дела обстоят получше и производство качественнее, но пока сам не нарвешься, можно делать как угодно.

Answer (score 0):

32-х разрядную XP **SP3** не удается заставить видеть 4 GB, а вот SP2 можно.

Comment: почему же? если мне не измняет память, то выход один - правка реестра ручками. Меняется один параметр - погуглите (на память не помню что менять) - и вуаля..

Comment: Вы имеете в виду /PAE параметр (только не в реестре, а в Boot.ini) ?Для 32-bit систем в SP2 работает, а в SP3 нет (исключен).

Answer (score 0):

32-розрядную систему вы никак не заставите увидеть а темболее заставить работать с 4 гигами оперативки...